# Recyclerview not showing firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, service, firebaseui

Code

```
public class PieOptions  extends Service {
    WindowManager wm;
    RelativeLayout ll;
    LayoutInflater li;

    String UID;
    String mFriend;
    private String userName;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private  DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;


    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    private RecyclerView mUsersList;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsersHelper, PieOptions.UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        final View myview;
        li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        myview = li.inflate(R.layout.service_pie, null);

        ImageButton mClose = (ImageButton) myview.findViewById(R.id.close);
        mUsersList = (RecyclerView) myview.findViewById(R.id.usersList);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        UID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(UID);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserData");

        mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AllUsersHelper> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AllUsersHelper>()
                        .setQuery(mDatabaseReference, AllUsersHelper.class)
                        .build();

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsersHelper, UsersViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsersHelper model) {
                holder.setName(model.getName());
                holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
                holder.setImage(model.getImage());

                final String userId = getRef(position).getKey();

                mUsersDatabase.orderByChild("Name");
                mUsersDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String mName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                        String mStatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                        String mDisplayImage = dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();

                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Online")) {
                            String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("Online").getValue().toString();
                            holder.setUserOnline(userOnline);
                        }
                        holder.setName(mName);
                        holder.setImage(mDisplayImage);
                        holder.setStatus(mStatus);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserData").child(userId);
                        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                userName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(PieOptions.this, FloatingWindow.class);
                                intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", userId);
                                intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", userName);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.all_users_layout, parent, false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,// | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        /////////////////////////Another params

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                750,1250,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;

        wm.addView(myview, params);
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams finalParameters = params;

        mClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wm.removeView(myview);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View mView;
        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            TextView mDisplayName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            mDisplayName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            TextView mDisplayStatus = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_status);
            mDisplayStatus.setText(status);
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            CircularImageView mDisplayImage = (CircularImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(mDisplayImage);
        }

        public void setUserOnline(String userOnline) {
            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.online);
            if(userOnline.equals("Online")){
                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Trying to display a recyclerview in a service. The service has no problem. Its inflating the layout. The code is fine because i have an activity with the same code so the code works fine. Im just not sure whether this is the right way to show recyclerview data in a service. Can someone help me out please?

The problem is the service is showing a blank window. Like everything else is shown except the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using a new version of FirebaseUI, to start listening for data(so the data appears in the recyclerView) you need to call `startListening()` method.

```
mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

Check here for more information:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#startstop-listening